# Getting past anti-CSRF to log a user into a site when you know their username and password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, cross-domain

This sounds a bit evil, bear with me though.  It's also not specifically a Rails question even though the two sites in question use Rails.  (Apologies in advance for both these things)

Imagine two websites which both use Ruby on Rails:

- mysite.com, on which i'm a developer and have full access in terms of changing code etc, and also have an admin login, so I can manage user accounts.
- theirsite.com, on which i have an admin login but no dev access.  I know the people who run it but i'd rather not ask them any favours for political reasons.  That is an option however.

Using my admin login on each site i've made a user account for the same person.  When they're logged into mysite.com, i'd like to be able to provide a button which logs them straight into theirsite.com.  I have their username and password for theirsite.com stored in their user record in the mysite.com database, to facilitate this.  The button is the submit button for a form which duplicates the form on the theirsite.com login page, with hidden fields for their username and password.

The stumbling block is that theirsite.com handles CSRF with an `authenticity_token` variable, which is failing validation when the login submits from mysite.com.

My first attempt to get past this was, in the mysite.com controller which loads the page with the form, to scrape the theirsite.com login page to get an authenticity token, and then plug that into my form.  But this isn't working.

If i load the theirsite.com login page, and the mysite.com page with the remote login button in two browser tabs, and manually copy the authenticity_token from the theirsite.com form to the mysite.com form, then it works.  This is because (i think) the authenticity_token is linked to my session via a cookie, and when i do it all in the same browser the session matches up, but when i get the authenticity token from theirsite.com via scraping (using Nokogiri but i could use curl instead) it's not the same session.

Question A) So, i think that i also need to set a cookie so that the session matches up between the browser and the Nokogiri request that i make.  But, this might be impossible, and exactly the sort of thing that the anti-CSRF system was designed to defeat.  Is that the case?

Question B) Let's say that i decide that, despite the politics, i need to ask the owner of theirsite.com to make a small change to allow me to log our users into theirsite.com when we know their theirsite.com username and password.  What would be the smallest, safest change that i could ask them to make to allow this?

Please feel free to say "Get off SO you evil blackhat", i think that's a valid response.  The question is a bit dodgy.

Comment: This feels a bit out of place on http://stackoverflow.com/ , I would think you may get a better response on http://serverfault.com/ or http://superuser.com/ .

Comment: hmm, thanks.  I wasn't sure: it's more programming-y than sysadmin-y but it's really a question about http i suppose...

Comment: Any idea which Rails version is theirsite.com is running on?

Comment: No.  I'm actually not 100% sure it *is* rails: that was just my guess on the fact that the auth token is called authenticity_token and also that the inputs look like they have the rails auto-generated classes and ids.

Comment: If I give my email address, can you provide me theirsite.com's address?

Comment: @Parry - no, sorry.  Thanks tho.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar can you expand on your point a bit please?

Comment: If you do go the ask them route (route B), I would ask them to implement an OAuth type of service so that you can do token based logins / requests?

Comment: maybe https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize code can help you in this question.

Comment: thanks for reading jvnill but as i say in another comment, browser automation isn't the answer: this is designed to be done by users of my mysite.com, not by devs or other people who would install special software.

Answer (score 3):

**A)** No, this is not possible as CSRF Protection is made to protect from actions like these only. So "***Get off SO you evil blackhat***"

As per the question I'm assuming that *theirsite.com* is using Rails(v3 or v4)

**B)** The smallest change that you could ask them to do is to make a special action for you, so that you could pass user credentials from your back-end and the user will be logged in from their on.

That action will work something like this :

You'll have a special code which will be passed along the credentials so that the request is verified on their servers. That code can either be a static predefined code or it can be generated on minute/hour/day basis with the same algorithm on both sites.

The function that you'd be asking to make for you will be like this:

Rails v3 and v4:

This action will be POST only.

```
#I'm supposing 'protect_from_forgery' is already done in theirsite.com
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery
end

#changes to be made are here as follows
class SomeController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:login_outside] #this turns off CSRF protection on specific actions

    def login_outside
        if(#check special code here)
            #Their login logic here
        end
    end
end
```

Check this link for further information on skipping CSRF protection in Rails

[Rails 4 RequestForgeryProtection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html)

Answer (score 2):

This shouldn't be too hard to do.

You need to send an ajax GET request to their signup page, copy the authenticity_token with javascript, and then send an ajax POST to the actual log in route that creates a session with the right credentials and authenticity_token.

One tricky part is finding out their log in route. Try `/sessions/new` or perhaps they have the url in the form, so look at the html there. Good luck!

The other tricky part is knowing how the parameters are usually sent. Check out the form's html. If all the `input` tags have `user_` before their name's then you'll need to structure your parameters similarly; i.e. `user_email`, `user_password`.

It's entirely possible to fetch the crsf token and submit your own form (because a log-in page is accessible to anyone!). However, it'll be difficult to know the details of their arrangement. The guessing and checking isn't too bad of an options (again, `/sessions/new` is how I route my log in; you should also try your route to see if they have a similar one.)

If that doesn't work, try taking a look at their github account! It's very possible they haven't paid $7 a month and it's open to the public. You will easily be able to view their routes and parameter parsings that way.

Good luck!

Comment: Hmm, an ajax call is being blocked by an `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` error.

Comment: Right. You'll need to use a Cross Domain Request, instead of the standard XMLHTTPRequest. You can do it in vanilla javascript: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/, use a javascript library: https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain, or use one of a couple jquery plugins: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2013/09/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-request.html#jsonp.   I would recommend using jQuery and jsonp, described in the last link. Good luck!

Comment: Hmm, thanks @Kites.  I have managed to log in using Curl, in the terminal, by saving the cookies, so i feel like i'm a bit closer to logging in in the browser, too.

Comment: Hi again @Kites.  I'm coming back to this again, nearly a year on.  We decided not to do it this way, but we've now got another reason to try it.  One thing that makes this easier is that i know a) all the parameters and routes etc involved, and b) know the username and password. So i've got all of the ingredients: it's just the CRSF that's the problem.

Comment: again:  in order to make the Cross Domain Request solution work, do i need to get `theirsite.com` to add a rule like `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http: // mysite.com"` to their server config? (spaces added to get past StackExchange comment validation)  This seems less dangerous than asking them to allow jsonp.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. The anti-csrf works like you send cookie to an user, and inject token in form of hidden field into a form; if the token matches with cookie form post is accepted. Now if you run form on your side, you can't set the cookie (as the cookie can be only set in domain of its origin).

If there is just some particular action you want to perform on their site, you can get away with browser automation. (i.e. your run browser on your server-side, script the action and execute it).

As for B) safest and smallest change is contradiction :) Smallest change would be to create handler for POST request on their side where you'll send username and password (this handler HAS TO run over https) and it will create auth cookie on their side.

As for safest - the whole concept of storing encrypted (not hashed) passwords is questionable at best (would you like your site to be listed here http://plaintextoffenders.com/ ?). Also if user changes his password on their side you're screwed. Secure solution would be that you'll store just 3pty UserID on your side, and you'll send asymmetrically encrypted UserID with Timestamp to their side (you'll encrypt it with your private key). They'll decrypt it (they'll have to have public key), validate if timestamp is not to old and if not they'll create auth cookie for given user id. There are also protocols for that (like SAML).

Comment: Thanks Ondrej.  Browser automation isn't the answer here as the users will be standard users, not me or other devs.  You're right that asking theirsite.com to make a change is the safest option.  I can live with the user not being able to log in automatically after they change their password: i don't think that will happen very often due to the nature of the site in question.  Also agree on the encrypted timestamped params approach - i've used that with other partners in the past.

Answer (score 0):

**A)**
What you are trying to do is really a form of a CSRF attack.

The idea behind a cross-site request forgery attack is that an attacker tricks a browser into performing an action as a user on some site, as the user who is using the site. The user is usually identified by a session identifier stored in a cookie, and cookies are sent along automatically. This means that without protection, an attacker would be able to perform actions on the target site.

To prevent CSRF, a site typically includes an anti-CSRF token in pages, which is tied to the session and is sent along in requests made from the legitimate site.
This works because the token is unpredictable, and the attacker cannot read the token value from the legitimate site's pages.

I could list various ways in which CSRF protection may be bypassed, but these all depend on on an incorrect implementation of the anti-CSRF mechanism. If you manage to do so, you have found a security vulnerability in theirsite.com.

For more background information about CSRF, see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF).

**B)**
The smallest change which theirsite.com could do is to disable the CSRF protection check for the login page.

CSRF protection depends on the unpredictability of requests, and for login pages, the secret password itself protects against CSRF. An extra check through an anti-CSRF token is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks @SvdB - this (A) was my suspicion too: it might not be possible.   Regarding (B), I don't think i could ask them to disable CRSF on any of their pages: that sounds too much i am asking them to compromise their security.